# How to extract a string from double quotes?

Tags: php, string, preg-match, preg-match-all, double-quotes

I have a string:

> This is a text, "Your Balance left $0.10", End 0

How can I extract the string in between the double quotes and have only the text (without the double quotes):

> Your Balance left $0.10

I have tried `preg_match_all()` but with no luck.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->between('"', '"')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L412) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As long as the format stays the same you can do this using a regular expression. `"([^"]+)"` will match the pattern

- Double-quote
- At least one non-double-quote
- Double-quote

The brackets around the `[^"]+`  means that that portion will be returned as a separate group.

```
<?php

$str  = 'This is a text, "Your Balance left $0.10", End 0';

//forward slashes are the start and end delimeters
//third parameter is the array we want to fill with matches
if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) {
    print $m[1];   
} else {
   //preg_match returns the number of matches found, 
   //so if here didn't match pattern
}

//output: Your Balance left $0.10
```

Comment: If you want to use it as an echo you can use `preg_replace` instead, ie: `{{ preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '$1', $str) }}` (Laravel) or `echo preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '$1', $str);`

Answer (score 20):

For everyone hunting for a full featured string parser, try this:

```
(?:(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])+")|(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])+'));
```

Use in preg_match:

```
$haystack = "something else before 'Lars\' Teststring in quotes' something else after";
preg_match("/(?:(?:\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])+\")|(?:'(?:\\\'|[^'])+'))/is",$haystack,$match);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Lars\' Teststring in quotes'
)
```

This works with single and double quoted string fragments.

Comment: Works but is there a way to exclude the quotes itself from the returned string?

Comment: Works nice except empty strings are not counted and get results messy. for example code let a="";let b=""; the first match will not be an empty result but it would rather be ";let b="

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
preg_match_all('`"([^"]*)"`', $string, $results);
```

You should get all your extracted strings in $results[1].

Answer (score 7):

Unlike other answers, this supports escapes, e.g. `"string with \" quote in it"`.

```
$content = stripslashes(preg_match('/"((?:[^"]|\\\\.)*)"/'));
```

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression `'"([^\\"]+)"'` will match anything between two double quotes.

```
$string = '"Your Balance left $0.10", End 0';
preg_match('"([^\\"]+)"', $string, $result);
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: Double quotes are being used as pattern delimiters in this snippet.  Do not use this snippet in your project.

Answer (score -9):

Just use str_replace and escape the quote:

```
str_replace("\"","",$yourString);
```

Edit:

Sorry, didnt see that there was text after the 2nd quote. In that case, I'd simply to 2 searches, one for the first quote and one for the 2nd quote, and then do a substr to extra all stuff between the two.

Comment: Its not event a valid regex!