# Php extract a string between double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract a string with any symbols between a doublequotes using preg_match including double quotes as well.

I've tried all solutions in the question below but nothing  has worked for my case:
[php to extract a string from double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017051/php-to-extract-a-string-from-double-quote)

**Sample string:** "ASD ""ASD ADS"""

I need to extract: ASD ""ASD ADS""

Current code which is working except I don't know how to handle the exception above which ruining whole structure:

```
$regex = '/"(.*)"/imU';
$content = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

return $matches[0];
```

Comment: Please post what code you have so far.

Comment: @NigelRen posted, can have a look

Comment: Remove `U` from regex

Comment: You can always try out regex's on something like https://regex101.com/ to check them out (including the flags you need)

Comment: @Pyton wow, that really worked, thank you so much, could you briefly explain why this U ruined the whole thing )))) thanks =)

Comment: One thing you'll have to be careful of is that it always looks for the last quote, so it doesn't care if they are balanced or not (i.e. `"ASD ""ASD ADS""" s"`)

Comment: @NigelRen yea definitely, but I'm wondering now why removing "U" make it work, even those expressions which are more complex and which include double quotes in didn't worked properly

Comment: `\U` is a modifier that makes the regex [ungreedy](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). In this case the `.*` will be `.*?` which will match until the first double quotes is encountered instead of the last.

Comment: Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

To serve properly 2 adjacent double quotes between the opening
and closing double quote, you must use 2 alternatives:
either a char **other than** the double quote or **2 consecutive**
double quotes.

So the regex can be as follows:

```
/"(?:[^"]|"")+"/g
```

Description:

- `"` - Match the "opening" double quote.
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group, needed due to the `+`
  quantifier after it.

  - `[^"]` - The first alternative - any char other than the
    double quote.
- `|` - Or.

  - `""` - Two double quotes.
- `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
- `+` - This group can occur 1 or more times.
- `"` - Match the "closing" double quote.

It is enough to use `g` option only.